# Cannot switch to Nvidia card from VGA, I get 'Error: BrokenCount > 0', can't update the libvdpau1 file

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, playonlinux, ubuntu-drivers

Ok, this is a weird one.

Using a HP Pavillion Slimline using Nvidia GeForce 6150SE nForce 430 with the driver 304.128 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Results from running

```
lshw
```

Show the following (not sure if all/any of this is relevant):

```
description: Desktop Computer
product: s5602la (BM437AA#ABM)
vendor: Hewlett-Packard
version: Chassis Version
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.5 dmi-2.5 vsyscall32
configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=103C_53316J G=D     sku=BM437AA#ABM uuid=8088F359-CB59-1610-A395-8546BA7CF8F9
  *-core
   description: Motherboard
   product: 2A99
   vendor: PEGATRON CORPORATION
   physical id: 0
   version: 6.01
   serial: 107396950000153
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
      physical id: 0
      version: 6.13
      date: 09/08/2010
      size: 64KiB
      capacity: 960KiB
      capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification

…

 *-pci:0
      description: PCI bridge
      product: MCP61 PCI bridge
      vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
      version: a1
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 66MHz
      capabilities: pci ht subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
 *-multimedia
      description: Audio device
      product: MCP61 High Definition Audio
      vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
      physical id: 5
      bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
      version: a2
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 66MHz
      capabilities: pm msi ht bus_master cap_list
      configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0 maxlatency=5 mingnt=2
      resources: irq:22 memory:fbff8000-fbffbfff
…

 *-pci:1
      description: PCI bridge
      product: MCP61 PCI Express bridge
      vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
      physical id: 9
      bus info: pci@0000:00:09.0
      version: a2
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pci pm msi ht pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
      configuration: driver=pcieport
      resources: irq:40
 *-pci:2
      description: PCI bridge
      product: MCP61 PCI Express bridge
      vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
      physical id: b
      bus info: pci@0000:00:0b.0
      version: a2
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pci pm msi ht pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
      configuration: driver=pcieport
      resources: irq:41
 *-pci:3
      description: PCI bridge
      product: MCP61 PCI Express bridge
      vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
      physical id: c
      bus info: pci@0000:00:0c.0
      version: a2
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pci pm msi ht pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
      configuration: driver=pcieport
      resources: irq:42
 *-display
      description: VGA compatible controller
      product: C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430]
      vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
      physical id: d
      bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
      version: a2
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 66MHz
      capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
      configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
      resources: irq:21 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f9000000-f9ffffff memory:fbfc0000-fbfdffff
```

I wanted to play League of Legends, so I successfully installed PlayOnLinux and LoL itself. I had VERY low FPS (around 10, tops) so I started looking for an answer to that. The only thing I could deduce that was missing for more FPS was a newer nvidia driver, so I tried installing version 331 (I was currently using 304).

I did this from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-331-updates
```

The installation for the 331 driver was unsuccessful, I got the blackscreen login loop, which I fixed by rebooting in recovery mode and then purging nvidia drivers and reinstalling 304 back again. I get an error message, stating that '/etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg' couldn't be overwritten and libvdpau1_1.1 gave an error code (1)

I tried removing both files from terminal using the 'rm' command and tried fixing it again with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

with the same results:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Correcting dependencies... Done
    The following extra packages will be installed:
    libvdpau1
    Suggested packages:
      nvidia-vdpau-driver vdpau-driver
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      libvdpau1
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    Need to get 0 B/26.4 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 120 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    (Reading database ... 1403913 files and directories          currently                 installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../libvdpau1_1.1-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libvdpau1:amd64 (1.1-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1) ...
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives        /libvdpau1_1.1-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
             trying to overwrite shared '/etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg', which         is        different from other instances of package         libvdpau1:amd64
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/libvdpau1_1.1-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Aftre the -f command, I got the same error as above. Also, I get the 'Error:  BrokenCount > 0' warning.

When trying to use the Ubuntu Software Center it said I can't install or update since my system is broken, along with this message: 'New software can't be installed, because there is a problem with the software currently installed. Do you want to repair this problem now?' I clicked on 'repair' and got this: 'Package operation failed. The installation or removal of a software package failed.' along with:

```
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 1403913 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libvdpau1_1.1-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvdpau1:amd64 (1.1-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives    /libvdpau1_1.1-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg', which is different     from other instances of package libvdpau1:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libvdpau1_1.1-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-settings:
 nvidia-settings depends on libvdpau1; however:
  Package libvdpau1:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-settings (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Then the Software Center crashed, and I got the following message: 'The package system is broken.
Check if you are using third party repositories.'

Not sure if this extra info is useful, but when running

```
lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12
```

I get the following:

```
00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce     6150SE nForce 430] [10de:03d0] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA     controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2a99]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21
    Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f9000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fbfc0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia

00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h     Processor HyperTransport Configuration [1022:1200]
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Also, when I input

```
sudo lshw -C display; lsb_release -a; uname -a:
```

I get this information:

```
 *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: d
   bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:21 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f9000000-f9ffffff memory:fbfc0000-fbfdffff

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

uname: invalid option -- ':'
Try 'uname --help' for more information.
```

So:

1. How can I fix this?
2. Can driver 331 be installed?

Thanks a lot!

---

`uname -a`

```
Linux alfredo-s5602la 3.13.0-66-generic #108-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 7 15:20:27 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`sudo apt-get remove libvdpau1`

```
[sudo] password for alfredo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libvdpau1' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-settings : Depends: libvdpau1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`sudo apt-get -f install`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjansson4 libxnvctrl0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libvdpau1
Suggested packages:
  nvidia-vdpau-driver vdpau-driver
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libvdpau1
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/27.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 124 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 1403926 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libvdpau1_1.1.1-0ubuntu0~gpu14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvdpau1:amd64 (1.1.1-0ubuntu0~gpu14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libvdpau1_1.1.1-0ubuntu0~gpu14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg', which is different from other instances of package libvdpau1:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libvdpau1_1.1.1-0ubuntu0~gpu14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`apt-cache policy libvdpau1`

```
libvdpau1:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.1.1-0ubuntu0~gpu14.04.1
  Version table:
     1.1.1-0ubuntu0~gpu14.04.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     0.7-1ubuntu0.1 0
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.7-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

`sudo dpkg -r --force-all libvdpau1:amd64`

```
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove libvdpau1:amd64, only the config
files of which are on the system; use --purge to remove them too
```

`sudo apt-get purge libvdpau1`

```
[sudo] password for alfredo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-settings : Depends: libvdpau1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or secify a solution).
```

Comment: Try to remove the `libvdpau1` package. `sudo apt-get remove libvdpau1` and add the output to your question by [edit] your question and not my answer =). We will reinstall the packages later again.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libvdpau1`

Comment: @A.B. I have posted the terminal output in my answer

Comment: Ok, try this… nuke the package. `sudo dpkg -r --force-all libvdpau1:amd64`

Comment: @A.B. is that by following your first answers? or  `sudo apt-get install nvidia-304 nvidia-304-updates` ?

Comment: Don't install via apt-get. Blacklist noveau as well, purge libvdpau1 and install the drivers using 'Propereitary Drivers' found in add or remove software.

Comment: @WeareBorg I wasn't able to purge libvdpau1, please refer to my terminal output, maybe I misstyped something or had wrong syntaxis?

Comment: Your libvdpau1 is locking the apt-get. Because of which its not getting removed, restart your pc and give command sudo apt-get purge libvdpau1   . After that, you can add the driver from the Proprietary driver thing. Enjoy.

Comment: @WeareBorg Yes, we know that! "Your libvdpau1 is locking the apt-get"

Comment: @A.manc Give me the output of `apt-cache policy libvdpau1:amd64`

Comment: Remove this PPA: `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-trusty.list; sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31070/discussion-on-question-by-a-manc-cannot-switch-to-nvidia-card-from-vga-i-get-e).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apt-get purge …` and `apt-get remove …` things seem to not work ! **:\**

There are some effective weapons such as

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all libvdpau1:amd64
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all libvdpau1:amd64
```

but somehow useless here ...

In the end ... the solution was just as simple as

```
sudo rm /etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

---

And no - you can not install newer drivers than 304 - they do not support GeForce 6150 SE GPU !

Comment: I did that and got 'sudo: ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa: command not found'

Comment: The command is `sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`

Comment: It is the libvdpau1 file again: 'The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-settings : Depends: libvdpau1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
/usr/sbin/ppa-purge: line 180: aptitude: command not found
Warning:  Something went wrong, packages may not have been reverted'

Comment: That's bad and I can't invite you into a chat. You need more points. Try this: `sudo apt-get install aptitude`

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. I have the whole messages from terminal, I've updated my question with those. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Hi @A.B. , haven't been able to fix this issue, any chance you have other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: My system wants to upgrade to 15.04, is this advisable with my packages disaster? will/could the upgrade fix anything?

Comment: No, that's not advisable.. But a fresh install would save some time, if that's an option for you.

Comment: If a fresh reinstall is the optimal solution, I'll backup all my files and do that. Any thread you recommend to follow instructions for this?